# Error `Async test method must have non-void return type` when upgrading from NUnit 2 to NUnit 3

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit-3.0

I have to refactor am unit test from NUNIT 2 to NUNIT 3 and the following syntax throws an error:

```
var expectedResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation = 
   () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => expectedResponseMessage);
```

Error:

> Async test method must have non-void return type

How may I rewrite this? I have tried many syntaxes but no luck.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error

> Async test method must have non-void return type

means that in NUnit 3+, an `async` Unit Test itself may *not* have a `void` return type (i.e. the method decorated with `[Test] / [TestCase]` etc). Instead, you can return an empty `Task` (**Correct way in newer versions of NUnit with async test support**):

```
[Test]
public async Task EnsureFoo()
{
     // Arrange

     // Act
     var myResult = await classBeingTested.DoSomethingAsync();

     // Assert
     Assert.IsNotNull(myResult);
     ...
}
```

In NUnit 2.x, this wasn't checked, so a `async void` unit test could slip into your unit test code base, i.e. of the form (**Bad, don't do this**)

```
[Test]
public async void Foo() // < -- Error : Async test method must have non-void return type
{
     var myResult = await classBeingTested.DoSomethingAsync();
     // Post continuation assertions here.
}
```

this is rather dangerous - the test can't be awaited<sup>*</sup>, and would return before any continuations completed - e.g. any failures in the `Asserts` done in the continuation might not be reported.

**Re : Your fake Task**

Scheduling a Task just to return a fake response seems overkill, i.e. in most tests you should be able to use `Task.FromResult` to replace:

```
Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation = 
   () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => expectedResponseMessage);
```

With the cheaper:

```
Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation = 
   () => Task.FromResult(expectedResponseMessage);
```

`Task.FromResult` returns an already completed task with the given return value - in most cases, this should suffice for your unit testing purposes, unless you really do want an independent Task to be executed on the threadpool.

---

<sub>* Actually, seemingly even earlier versions such as NUnit 2.6.4 had already identified the issue with `async void` tests, and [incorporated a workaround](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit/)</sub>